# How to track down a file descriptor leak?

Tags: lsof, max-file-descriptors

I have a java process (Glassfish) which is leaking file descriptors.  I know this because I get the helpful `java.io.IOException: Too many open files` exception.  I can look in `/proc/PID#/fd` and see all the open file descriptors.  When I use lsof I get a very large number of entries like this:

> java    18510 root 8811u  sock                0,4           1576079 can't identify protocol
>   java    18510 root 8812u  sock                0,4           1576111 can't identify protocol
>   java    18510 root 8813u  sock                0,4           1576150 can't identify protocol

I see 12 new ones created per minute.  What options can I use on lsof or what other tools are available to me to help track down socket file descriptors where the protocol can't be identified?

Comment: // , A lot of great responses to this question are but a search engine query away... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+track+down+a+file+descriptor+leak

Answer (score 7):

to see the top 20 file handle using processes:

```
for x in `ps -eF| awk '{ print $2 }'`;do echo `ls /proc/$x/fd 2> /dev/null | wc -l` $x `cat /proc/$x/cmdline 2> /dev/null`;done | sort -n -r | head -n 20
```

the output is in the format file handle count, pid, cmndline for process

example output

```
701 1216 /sbin/rsyslogd-n-c5
169 11835 postgres: spaceuser spaceschema [local] idle
164 13621 postgres: spaceuser spaceschema [local] idle
161 13622 postgres: spaceuser spaceschema [local] idle
161 13618 postgres: spaceuser spaceschema [local] idle
```

Answer (score 4):

Become familiar with the strace command.  It monitors system calls.  I recently used it to track down file descriptor leaks that were causing our snmpd daemon to crash repeatedly.  It takes some getting used to, but it's a powerful tool.

You can use strace to attach to a running process (don't forget the -f flag to follow child processes).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to track down?  The remote IP address(es) associated with the leaked FDs, the defective code, or something else?

As you've already identified that there is a leak, contacting the engineers responsible for this java process seems like a reasonable next step.

Comment: I'm trying to track down any information I can about those file descriptors.  `can't identify protocol` doesn't give the engineers much to run with.  Are there tools or options in lsof that I'm not seeing which I should be using?

The problem doesn't happen in the test env and only started in this env after a cabinet migration.  The same code had no issues before the migration and when the appl is undeployed, Glassfish still leaks on its own.  My best guess is something broke from a networking perspective and sockets are trying to initialize but can't and then they hang and are left around.